# Can Spring JPA Auditing audit the User Entity itself?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Here is what I am trying to implement in Spring Boot-

```
public class User extends  AbstractAuditable<User, Long>{
    Long userId;
    String userNAme;
    String password
}
```

When I try to run the test and have  UserRepository injected, the context fails to load with he following reason -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.example.User] does not define an IdClass
```

Comment: Add com.example.User class.Also remove extends and check

Comment: @RajaRamachandran. Tried that already. It works. The test blows up only when it's self auditing.

Comment: You need an Id annotation on the `userId`